# Golang Overlay image always black and white

Tags: image, go

I am trying to put an overlay on qrcode(image). The problem is my original overlay image is colored but the end result is black and white. Below is the code:

```golang
func (e Encoder) Encode(str string, logo image.Image, size int) (*bytes.Buffer, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    code, err := qr.New(str, e.QRLevel)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    img := code.Image(size)
    e.overlayLogo(img, logo)

    err = png.Encode(&buf, img)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &buf, nil
}


func (e Encoder) overlayLogo(dst, src image.Image) {

    offset := dst.Bounds().Max.X/2 - src.Bounds().Max.X/2
    yOffset := dst.Bounds().Max.Y/2 - src.Bounds().Max.Y/2
    draw.Draw(dst.(draw.Image), dst.Bounds().Add(image.Pt(offset, yOffset)), src, image.Point{}, draw.Over)
}
```

Can someone please help me here?
[image: This is the final image that I'm getting]

[Image Used](https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/xenatt/minimalism/128/App-Twitter-icon.png)

Comment: What is the type of the destination image? It may not be able to hold colored pixels. Also how are you encoding the result? That encoding process may strip away color information and use only black and white in the output. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I've added the encoding part to the question. Also, the destination image is created using https://github.com/skip2/go-qrcode . It's PNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QR code images use 2 colors which makes them easier to scan / recognize. The library you're using [`github.com/skip2/go-qrcode`](https://github.com/skip2/go-qrcode) creates paletted images that use 2 colors only (black and white by default). You can check the source code of [`QRCode.Image()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/skip2/go-qrcode#QRCode.Image) method you're calling, [source here](https://github.com/skip2/go-qrcode/blob/da1b6568686e89143e94f980a98bc2dbd5537f13/qrcode.go#L286):

```
p := color.Palette([]color.Color{q.BackgroundColor, q.ForegroundColor})
img := image.NewPaletted(rect, p)
```

This means whatever you draw on such images, color for each pixel will be chosen from this 2-sized palette (either back or white). The color information of the drawn image will be lost.

If you want to retain all the colors, you must create an image that supports all (or at least the used) colors, draw the QR code image on that, and then the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

My work needs it too. So from @icza I summarized :-

```
resultImg := image.NewRGBA(qrImg.Bounds())
overlayLogo(resultImg, qrImg)
overlayLogo(resultImg, logo)
```

So we get the resultImg, QR code with logo.